# React: Return Function Result from Seperate file

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and currently learning through building out a project.

I have a file called Function.js that contains a function that I import into my components file (Component.js).

I am trying to return the value of a function in Function.js and insert it into a div but im not too sure how to tackle this...

Function.js

```js
let testVariable;
export const getValue = (getValue) => {
    switch (getIC) {
        case "testing":
            testVariable = "VALUE"
    }
    return testVariable
}
```

Component.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getValue } from "./testfunc";

function StatusHubContent() {
const [getIC, getValueState] = useState("");

getValue(getIC)

  return (
    <div class="columns is-vcentered">
        <div class="select">
          <select
            id="ic"
            onChange={(e) => {
              getValueState(e.target.value);
            }}
          >
            <option selected disabled>
              Person
            </option>
            <option value="Person A">Person A</option>
            <option value="Person B">Person B</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>{getValue}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Im stuck on how I could return the value in `<div></div>`

Thanks all!

Comment: In the body of StatusHubContent Component, save the result of your function call to some variable, i.e. `const valueToShow = getValue(getIC)` and then use this varibale in JSX: `<div>{valueToShow}</div>`

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! Thats all I was missing!!

Comment: yeah but that will not be efficeient. you should use state and the useEffect hook  to assign variables instead of assigning them directly or the getValue function will be called on every state change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you working on, Maybe i can be of help.
Anyways here's what i've came up with

Functions.js

```js
let testVariable;
export const getValue = (value) => {
    switch (value) {
        case "testing":
            testVariable = "VALUE"
    }
    return testVariable
}
```

Component.js

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getValue } from "./testfunc";

function StatusHubContent() {
const [state, setState] = React.useState(null)

return (
    <div class="columns is-vcentered">
        <div class="select">
          <select
            id="ic"
            onChange={(e) => setState(getValue(e.target.value))}
          >
            <option selected disabled>
              Incident Commander
            </option>
            <option value="ayushl">Ayush Lal</option>
            <option value="barriep">Barrie Pocock</option>
            <option value="joeld">Joel Douglas</option>
            <option value="nevashr">Nevash Reddy</option>
            <option value="schalkb">Schalk Burger</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div>{state}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir. Atthough for some weird reason, no matter which option I select, it always gets me the last value only

Comment: look like im getting undefined when logging the {state} and by default from the switch/case its picking the last value assignment

Comment: Try adding a default statement and remove the return at the end i don't know anymore